# Conjunction of Clauses and Well-Formed Formulas

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

Here is a theorem in my notes:

> If $\phi$ is any wff such that $\neg \phi$ is not a tautology, then $\phi$ is tautologically equivalent to a conjunction of clauses.

My question is that...can this theorem hold if $\phi$ is not a tautology and so $\neg \phi$ is tautologically equivalent to a conjunction of clauses?

Comment: How would you write a tautology as a conjunction of clauses?  Does your definition allow $x \vee \neg x$ as a clause?

Comment: Apply the theorem to $\lnot \phi$ : "If $\lnot \phi$ is any wff such that $¬¬ \phi$ (i.e. $\phi$) is not a tautology, then $\lnot \phi$ is tautologically equivalent to a conjunction of clauses."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - Sorry, I wrote the answer while you were writing your comment. If you rewrite your comment as an answer, I can delete my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Short answer.* Yes, it does.

*Long answer.* The statement:

> If $\varphi$ is any wff such that $\varphi$ is not a tautology, then $\lnot \varphi$ is tautologically equivalent to a conjunction of clauses.

is a corollary of the theorem stated in your question. Indeed, if $\varphi$ is any wff such that $\varphi$ is not a tautology, then $\lnot \varphi$ is a wff and $\lnot \lnot \varphi$ (which is equivalent to $\varphi$) is not a tautology. According to the theorem stated in your question (applied to $\lnot \varphi$), $\lnot \varphi$ is tautologically equivalent to a conjunction of clauses.

Comment: In the theorem from the notes, the "such that $\neg \phi$ is not a tautology" part is redundant.  There are plenty of ways to write $\phi$ as a conjunction of clauses if $\neg \phi$ is a tautology. If clauses like $x \vee \neg x$ are not allowed, then if $\phi$ is a tautology (as opposed to $\neg \phi$) then $\phi$ has no equivalent conjunction of clauses.